# What is the correct format for location that works with azure iot central's device property?

Tags: azure-iot-central

I updated a device property with location floating points like (11.111, -116.11) and in dms format but seems like the Azure map in dashboard doesn't get updated. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .Net API, the location can be specified as below (code example):

```
TwinCollection reportedProperties = new TwinCollection();

reportedProperties["devicelocation"] = new { lon= 122, lat= 45 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the location device property payload:

“devicelocation”: {
      “lat”: 122,
      “lon”: 45
      }

In this example, "devicelocation" is the field name that you will have to declare when defining the device model.

Comment: I'm struggling with this issue too, and tried that snippet but can't manage to get the device properties set on iOT Central. In  my case the property is named "location_data_key" and when I send the data I can only see ```[object object]```. Can you elaborate your answer, please?

Comment: @Rodrigo - can you share the code here? There are [code/firmware samples](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/blob/master/MXCHIP/mxchip_advanced/src/telemetry.cpp) that have examples on how to send location data as a reported property to IoT Central.